# What should I call this poker hand with a straight?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Hmmm, looks like a good hand... I'm certain I can make a straight out of this!  What should I call it? (6 2 8)

[image: 8 card hand]

Comment: Very clever construction!

Comment: @hexomino Agreed. For a while I thought the 8 card was a dud, so sure was I that the spades are normally aligned on it in two columns of 4. Once I finally realised I had completely misremembered that, the truth jumped out at me! :)

Comment: @Stiv Great solve too! Slightly related that the eight of diamonds looks like it has an 8 in the middle due to this arrangement.

Comment: Oh wow this is clever. Great puzzle!

Comment: After seeing the solution, it seems to me that the 3 and the 8 are in the wrong order - am I missing something?

Comment: @htmlcoderexe My thought was to put them enough in order that it was clear the answer was intentional but not make it a simple verbatim as this is already a pretty easy question. But your idea might have been better, given how little I mixed it up. I'm actually surprised this question is so popular, I prefer harder questions myself and almost didn't post it... But it was so much fun to construct that I did anyway.

Comment: It is a really fun puzzle, I mostly noticed because the rest were already in order just with those two swapped - hence triggering my "huh, this is slightly off" feeling. I don't think it did anything for making it more or less difficult.

Comment: FWIW While solving it I just applied a left-to-right order in two rows, rather than a hand order, so the ordering works visually in that regard :)

Comment: No, these cards cannot make a straight in poker. They are all of the same suit, so any combination is either a _flush_ or a _straight flush_. Mixed suits would be needed to make a _straight_.

Comment: I was trying to connect-the-dots the spades to get a toilet shape...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You should call this a...

> [**Strait of Magellan**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strait_of_Magellan) (after the famous sea route).

Because...

> The positions of the visible spades should be interpreted as [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille). When this is done, the cards spell out **MAGELLAN**:
>
>  [image: Image annotated with Braille interpretation]
>
>  Combining this with a pun on the poker term, 'straight', gives us the answer!

Comment: What is the meaning of `(6 2 8)` ?

Comment: @mountrix That's the enumeration for the answer, like for a crossword clue - it tells you that you're looking for 3 words, of 6, 2 and 8 letters in length :)